Proving for $A\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$, if $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$, then $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$
By definition, the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of a matrix $A$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$. A scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if there exists a nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb{F}^n$ such that
$$Av = \lambda v \iff (A-\lambda I)v=0.$$
For the above equation to have a nontrivial solution $v \ne 0$, the matrix $A-\lambda I$ must be singular. To my understanding, this happens when the determinant is zero (I don't know if it is "if and only if"). Then $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. And the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A = \det(A -\lambda I)$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of this polynomial. By the definition of an eigenvalue, if $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$, then $p_A = \det(A -\lambda I) = 0$.
So the statement is true, right? I just want to verify if my procedure is correct and the if and only if part.

Yes, singular if and only if determinant zero.

\begin{align*}\lambda\in\sigma(A)&\iff A-\lambda I_n\text{ is not injective}\\
&\iff A-\lambda I_n\text{ is not invertible} &&\text{($``\implies$" as $A-\lambda I_n$ is a matrix)}\\&\iff \det(A-\lambda I_n)=0\end{align*}
